# Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate con python 3.7

Tags: python, tkinter, matplotlib

tengo un botón que al momento de dar click manda a llamar a la función que gráfica un conteo de elementos, todo bien hasta ahí, pero ya sea cuando quiero cerrar la ventana o simplemente quiero hacer otra acción en el programa, python se detiene y me regresa el siguiente error:

```
  Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate
  Current thread 0x00002f20 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\PIIC\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5.py", line 1099 in mainloop
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\PIIC\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 3311 in show
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\PIIC\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py", line 413 in wrapper
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\PIIC\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 269 in show
  File "C:\Users\EdgKrg27\Desktop\Programas\Python\PIIC\proceso.py", line 151 in grafCount
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\PIIC\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705 in __call__
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\PIIC\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1283 in mainloop
  File "C:\Users\EdgKrg27\Desktop\Programas\Python\PIIC\interface.py", line 275 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983 in _find_and_load
  File "C:/Users/EdgKrg27/Desktop/Programas/Python/PIIC/main.py", line 4 in <module>
```

Alguien sabe a que se debe esto y como puedo arreglarlo. El código del botón es el siguiente:

```
import proceso
import tkinter as tk
p_proc = proceso.processing()
...
submenu2.add_command(label='Conteo', command=p_proc.grafCount)
...
```

El código de la función que manda a llamar es el siguiente:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
class processing:
    ...
    def grafCount(self):
        mi = np.min(datos)
        ma = np.max(datos)
        arGen = np.array([0.251666, 0.274943, 0.189580, 0.280461, 0.281545, 0.298050, 0.289700, 0.299061, 0.275021, 0.249371, 0.243430, 0.309093, 0.298730, 0.280584, 0.265523, 0.253661, 0.261174, 0.279146, 0.257026, 0.299477, 0.136880, 0.273131, 0.256942, 0.264761, 0.288771, 0.266248, 0.310594, 0.236013, 0.272708, 0.272186, 0.234633, 0.270377, 0.103838, 0.290640, 0.050274, 0.081713, 0.036325, 0.211744])
        bins = np.round(np.linspace(mi, ma, 15), 4)
        plt.hist(arGen, bins,rwidth=0.5, color='red' )
        plt.title("Conteo de particulas")
        plt.xlabel('Tamaño')
        plt.ylabel('Cantidad')
        plt.show()
    ...
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda comunidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en la forma que creas el **plot**. Estás ejecutando `ptl.show()` dentro de tkinter y para poder ejecutar correctamente matplotlib sin problemas, se debe crear la gráfica sobre una *figura* y está se le pasa como parametro a `FigureCanvasTkAgg` para que quede embebido en la aplicación y tkinter tenga el control total de los eventos puesto que tkinter *no es Thread-safe*.

Fijate por favor en el siguiente ejemplo https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html?highlight=figurecanvastkagg

[image: Gráfica]

Saludos.

Comment: Genial, Eduardo_ muchas gracias por la información, le voy a dar una leída a lo que me recomendaste para poderle dar solución a mi problema, muchas gracias de nuevo.